# php-devel failed on installation red-hat 6

Tags: php, redhat, mongodb

I'm trying to install `mongodb` driver with `pecl` and for this i need `phpize (php-devel)`.
Does anyone know how can i resolve this issue or there is another way to install `php-mongodb driver`?

I try as suggested :
using `--skip-broken` to work around the problem
and running: `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`
Didn't work either

```
sudo yum install php-devel
```

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6 for package: php-devel-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (shared-rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6)
           Requires: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Installed: php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Available: php-5.3.2-6.el6.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.2-6.el6
           Available: php-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.2-6.el6_0.1
           Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-3.el6
           Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_1.3.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-3.el6_1.3
           Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.5
           Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
           Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8
           Available: php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
           Available: php-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Available: php-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i have manage to install php-devel by download the rpm and installing it.

**The result of yum list installed | grep php :**

```
php.x86_64                      5.3.3-27.el6_5     @cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod
php-cli.x86_64                  5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-6        
php-common.x86_64               5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-6        
php-devel.x86_64                5.3.3-27.el6_5     installed                    
php-gd.x86_64                   5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-6        
php-mbstring.x86_64             5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6
php-mcrypt.x86_64               5.3.3-1.el6        @epel-rhel-x86_64-server-6   
php-mysql.x86_64                5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-6        
php-pdo.x86_64                  5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-6        
php-pear.noarch                 1:1.9.4-4.el6      @cust_drv-rhel-x86_64-server-6-default-nonprod
php-xml.x86_64                  5.3.3-27.el6_5     @rhel-x86_64-server-6
```

**result of pecl install mongo**

```
downloading mongo-1.4.5.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.4.5.tgz (141,417 bytes)
..............................done: 141,417 bytes
84 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
shtool at '/var/tmp/mongo/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

**result of phpize** :

```
 phpize
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

Comment: Could you show output of the # yum list installed | grep php

Comment: Add result of list yum list installed. my final goal is to install mongo-db php driver. didn't know it will be so hard.

Comment: This package is already in EPEL, named `php-pecl-mongo`. Why are you trying to compile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (shared-rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6)
           Requires: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Installed: php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
```

Your version of php is higher than the available php-devel.
Either downgrade php to 5.3.3-22 or find a channel/repo that offers you the later version of php-devel.

Comment: pecl install mongo still not working for me. even that i installed php-devel from fedora repo.
I manually installed the php-mongo-driver and its working now.